# How uses Xpath 2.0 in Katalon Studio

Tags: java, xpath, saxon, katalon-studio, xpath-2.0

I want to know how can I use the **XPath 2.0** queries in **Katalon Studio**? I need to use an `ends-with` match. I found out that any browsers that I have tried to use (including Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE) do not support **XPath 2.0** queries. This way, how can I use those queries on a web test?

Comment: Although XPath 2.0 (indeed XPath 3.1) is now available in any modern browser via the Saxon-JS library, I strongly suspect there is no way that you can exploit this within Katalon Studio. Who knows though: if you ask them nicely...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Katalon Studio` supports XPath 2.0 expressions (like `ends-with` function).
But you have alternatives. Assuming you want to select the following element :

```
<div id="foo_bar">I love stackoverflow</div>
```

If you want to target it with its attribute, use a CSS selector :

```
div[id$='_bar']
```

Select a `div` element whith an `id` attribute which ends (`$=`) with "_bar"

If you want to target the element with its content, use the following XPath (1.0) :

```
//div[substring(.,string-length(.)-string-length('stackoverflow')+1)="stackoverflow"]
```

Select a `div` element with content ending with "stackoverflow".

In the future, if you need to test your XPath 1.0/2.0 expressions, you can use the following webservices :

- http://xpather.com/
- https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html
- http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Comment: Unfortunately, the ID of css element that I trying to get is dinamic, this way I need to create a object searching by Xpath.

I got an object with Xpath:
"//mat-dialog-container[@id='mat-dialog-26']/app-altera-valores-contratuais-form/input"

I need to create a new object with Xpath:
"app-altera-valores-contratuais-form/input"

PS: In Theory, katalon support xpath 2.0 expressions
https://imgur.com/hV2OAdF

Comment: Hmm. It's likely the XPath is translated to a regular 1.0 expression, if you select "ends-with" in the dropdown menu. Even if your `id` is dynamic, it won't be a problem to select the element holding it with a good anchor point. Please post the relevant HTML code in order to build the adequate XPath expression.

Comment: I have a list with many buttons with same label, that had this following xpath: `//mat-list-item[**9**]/div/div[2]/h3/div/button/span`, that number 9 is dynamic. (https://imgur.com/XudAbED)

Comment: `//mat-list-item[**9**]` means the `mat-list-item element` in the `**9**` position. You're really sure about that ?
You probably meant to write `//mat-list-item[@foo="**9**"]` or `//mat-list-item[text()="**9**"]` ? If the number 9 is dynamic, please post the fixed parts (`** **` : are these letters/numbers ?). Or better : a screenshot of the dynamic `mat-list-item element`. Hard to write this XPath blindfolded.:)